# Referential integrity of a hierarchy in sql

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to model the identification of securities that Bloomberg do.

**First they have a structure for a exchange and a group of exchanges (they call it a composite).**

Example 1 (United States):

[image]

Example 2 (Euro Zone):

[image]

**Second they identify a security using a ticker plus a exchange code:**

Ticker + exchange code

I.e. they describe a security with a name and a place in which is traded.

Example 1 (Stock of IBM at United States)

[image]

Example 2 (Stock of IBM at Euro Zone)

[image]

**Question:** How I keep the referential integrity of the tree of securties?

The problem is the next, if you have the next ER diagram:

[image]

If you have in the table of Codes the next:

[image]

Then the current configuration don't avoid inserting "IBM UP" without previously having inserted "IBM US" (the parent)

Comment: Just for do it once: why the downvote?

Comment: I guess because the question is not clear. Hierarchy, Bloomberg,IBM, security... What is this all about? And downvote is not mine.

Comment: @gofr1 thanks, I modified it, could you see it if now is more clear?

Comment: Yes, it is much better now! I'll never get that lists were hierarchic structures

Comment: Well, a referential integrity in a tree can be enforced directly through FOREIGN KEYs. Is there anything specific about that, with which you need some help?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic thanks for the commentary, the problem is for example if you insert IBM UP, you must insert first his parent IBM US.

Comment: @rlartiga Yes, that's how referential integrity works: you can't insert a child unless/until parent exists.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic ok I explain the problem in the question for more clarity. Please look it.